# Run Compose functions on emulator and check preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Compose and I would like to display the compose function on my emulator. I am getting the below error. I have a few question to clear up the concept. I also review other questions on SO but it didn't help.

1. How do I run individual composable functions?
2. How do I check the live preview of each function?
3. How to check my onCreate() with all layout?

I am using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2

Here is my effort.

```
     package ca.temi.jetpackcomposedemo

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import ca.temi.jetpackcomposedemo.layout.*
import ca.temi.jetpackcomposedemo.ui.theme.JetpackComposeDemoTheme

class DisplayContent : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

          /*  JetpackComposeDemoTheme {
                androidx.compose.material.Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Column {
                        SimpleText()
                        StringResourceText()
                        ParameterText(name = "@rpit")
                        ColorText()
                        BigText()
                        FontStyleText()
                    }
                }
            }*/

        }
    }
}


/**
 * Simple TextView
 */
//@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi=true)
@Composable
fun SimpleText() {
    Text(
        "Hello World"
    )
}

/**
 * Get Value from String file
 */
//@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi=true)
@Composable
fun StringResourceText() {
    Text(
        stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)
    )
}

/**
 * Pass Parameter And display value on Textview
 */
//@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi=true)
@Composable
fun ParameterText(name: String) {
    Text(
        "Helloo $name"
    )
}

/**
 * Change color of textview
 */
//@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi=true)
@Composable
fun ColorText() {
    Text(
        text = "This is Blue Color",
        color = Color.Blue
    )
}

/**
 *  Increase size of text view
 */
//@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi=true)
@Composable
fun BigText() {
    Text(
        "Big Text",
        fontSize = 30.sp
    )
}

/**
 * Change font appearance on TextView
 */

//@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi=true)
@Composable
fun FontStyleText() {
    Text(
        "This is Italic",
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Cursive,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
    )
}

//@Preview(showBackground = true)
//@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi=true)
@Composable
fun CustomFontFamily() {
    Text(
        "This is custom font", fontFamily = EBGaramond
    )
}


val EBGaramond = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_bold),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_bold_italic),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_extra_bold),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_extra_bold_italic),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_italic, FontWeight.Light),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_medium, FontWeight.Thin),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_medium_italic, FontWeight.ExtraLight),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_regular, FontWeight.SemiBold),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_semi_bold, FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.eb_garamond_semi_bold_italic, FontWeight.Black)
)


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    JetpackComposeDemoTheme {
        Column {
            SimpleText()
            StringResourceText()
            ParameterText(name = "@rpit")
            ColorText()
            BigText()
            FontStyleText()
        }
    }
}
```

Error running on Emulator

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ca.temi.jetpackcomposedemo, PID: 4417
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ca.temi.jetpackcomposedemo.ComposableSingletons$DisplayContentKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(DisplayContent.kt:24)
    at ca.temi.jetpackcomposedemo.ComposableSingletons$DisplayContentKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(DisplayContent.kt:22)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:410)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:166)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3337)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2582)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2522)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:478)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:748)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:907)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.and
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out [Why isn't it good to ask multiple questions and answers in one question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371614/3585796)

Comment: It is basically one question but I divided into three for easy to understand. @PylypDukhov

Answer (score 1):

**First Question**
Annotate every function that you want to see the preview of, with,

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
```

You might need to scroll through or expand the design window to see the result and might have to refresh the layout as well.

**Second Question**
Till now preview of jetpack compose is bit slow especially if you have a low end system. You have to refresh layout almost every time to see the updated results. And for live preview you can see a button at top of every preview upon hovering over that states "Start interactive mode". Upon clicking, it will start the interactive mode of that particular preview in which you can click, scroll, edit text etc.

**For Third Question**
You need to put all of your function in a function that contains a block with the theme name of your app. So, for example if I have an app named JetpackComposeDemo, it's theme will be names JetpackComposeDemoTheme.
So, in block setContent{}, you will have to call the block of JetpackComposeDemoTheme{} and put all of your functions inside this block to see them in your app.
Same, goes if you want to see all of their preview at once, you'll have to put them in the function like this,

```
@Preview(showBackGround = true, showSystemUi=true)
 @Composable
fun ShowALL() {
JetpackComposeDemoTheme{
//all of your functions here
}
}
```

But, looking at your code, your functions does note have any connections in between, so in case of being shown in one preview they will just stack over each other.

For more detailed guide on Jetpack Compose follow these [Codelabs](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose) by google.

Comment: Thank you for response@Kashif. I tried @Preview but I am getting error message on preview screen. "Failed to instantiate Composition Local"

Comment: Did you restructure your code according to rest of the things as well?

Comment: Yes I did, and I am getting same error I mentioned above.

Comment: Please check my updated code on question @Kashif

Comment: Instead of adding a column directly in theme block. Put it in a composable function and then add that function to the theme block.